# Performance impact of using GUID in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have tried searching this before asking but every result I have found mentions GUIDs as a PK which is not the case here.

I have a database that's using INT as the PK on all tables. However the data is accessed via API calls and a requirement was for the INT value not to be returned or used in any API. Therefore I thought of having an extra column on the tables containing a GUID.

Now my question is, if I Index the GUID column what kind of performance impact will this have? Would it be positive or negative? Bear in mind the GUID is NOT a PK or FK.

Comment: If you create an index on this column, you will get better performance on any search based on GUID; because that's what indexes are for.

Comment: As every index, adding a new index will add more work in insert/update/delete, For the select operations instead it will be useful only if you search on that column

Comment: If you place an index on the guid, the performance impact will be an index seek followed by an key lookup on gets vs a simple key lookup, plus the overhead of maintaining an additional index (probably only on insert/delete as you're unlikely to need to change the guid for an existing row?). That would be a negative, but not necessarily significantly. You need to test it on a representative volume of data and determine whether the performance is acceptable for your use case.

Comment: Sort of a strange requirement that the PrimaryKey not be presented in any API call. This is forcing you to have two unique values per row which is a waste of resources. What is the reason behind not using the PK in your API but a GUID is ok?

Comment: @SeanLange Probably because using a sequential integer can be a security issue for API calls

Comment: Read [GUIDs as primary key and clustering key](www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) and basically *anything* that Kimberly Tripp has written on what impact a badly chosen primary / clustering key has on your database - and yes, she **definitely** does **NOT** recommend GUID^s as primary keys (and clustering keys)

Comment: @SeanLange . . . The most amazing things can happen when lawyers get a hold of privacy laws.  I have had similar requests about internal identifiers.  Also, some companies shy away from returning auto incremented values, because it can inadvertently release other information -- such as how many customers they have.

Comment: And how many times have we seen the security switch this to a sequentialID instead of an actual guid which makes the whole argument kind of silly. And to expand on the GUID as a primary key it is perfectly fine as long as it is NOT the clustered index.

Comment: In this questions specific case you probably want to formally add a unique non clustered index to each guid column where it is a psuedo alias for PK.

Comment: @SeanLange - The reason for not using the incremental INT in API calls is for the exact reason GordonLinoff mentioned. It will expose figures we don't want the external caller knowing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but don't take it from me...

In the comments section on one of Kimberly Tripp's articles, she responds to a comment that advocates the opposite of your position, and she disagrees and argues for the same solution you are proposing (nonclustered indexed guid with a clustered int/bigint primary key).

> Herman:
>
> If the GUID is the intrinsic identifier for the entity being modelled (i.e. used by selects) then it should be the clustered primary key without question. The reason is that adding a surrogate identity key (of int or bigint) and demoting the GUID primary key to a column with an index/unique constraint requires 2 indexes to be maintained and slows down, in my experience, by a factor of 2.
>
> ---
>
> Kimberly Tripp 
>   Hey there Herman – Actually, I disagree. For point-based queries using a nonclustered index does not add a significant amount of *costly* IOs. And, the maintenance of a nonclustered index that’s heavily fragmented is a lot cheaper than the required maintenance on a heavily fragmented clustered index. Additionally, the GUID might make your nonclustered indexes unnecessarily wide – making them take: more log space, more disk space, more cache as well as adding time on insert and access (especially in larger queries/joins). 
> So, while you might not feel like an arbitrary/surrogate key is useful (because you never directly query against it) it can be incredibly efficient to use indirectly through your nonclustered indexes. There’s definitely an element of “it depends” here but if you have even just a few nonclustered indexes then it’s likely to be more beneficial than negative and often significantly so.
>
> Cheers,
>   kt ~ [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key - Kimberly L. Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)

Answer (score 3):

This should be fine.  Of course, you have the normal impact of any index and any column taking up more space.  So, data modifications will be a bit slower.  The use of a GUID to locate a record versus an integer is slightly slower.  Unless you have a very high throughput application, these are probably not important considerations.

One key point is that the GUID column should not be clustered.  This is very important because GUIDs are random, but primary keys are ordered.  If a GUID were used for a clustered index, almost every insert would go between two existing records, requiring a lot of movement of data.  By contrast, an identity column as a clustered index always inserts at the end of the data.

I am guessing that your references on GUIDs have discussed this issue.

Comment: Primary Keys in SQL Server are not required to be Clustered (Ordered).

Comment: What about using sequential guids?

Comment: Erik: Primary Keys are not required to be Clustered, but they are Ordered - all indexes are.

Comment: @Evk, with sequential guids you loose one great benefit of using guids. Generated GUIDS are unique in nature, which helps when correlating data, merging databases, etc. Unlike sequential keys, guids will be different even across various instances of the application, whether is horizontal scaling, separate geographical instances or just different environments (prod, test, etc.) I have also found guids handy when having to rollback the database and restore data created after the backup was taken.